# Spring boot Jobrunr no servers available error

Tags: java, spring-boot, cron, jobs, job-scheduling

Hi im trying to use jobrunr to enqueue a simple method and see that at dashboard but when i run my app it throws this exception

> org.jobrunr.JobRunrException: JobRunr encountered a problematic exception. Please create a bug report (if possible, provide the code to reproduce this and the stacktrace)
> at org.jobrunr.JobRunrException.shouldNotHappenException(JobRunrException.java:33)
> at org.jobrunr.server.ServerZooKeeper.lambda$determineIfBackgroundJobServerIsMaster$0(ServerZooKeeper.java:99)
> at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:408)
> at org.jobrunr.server.ServerZooKeeper.determineIfBackgroundJobServerIsMaster(ServerZooKeeper.java:99)
> at org.jobrunr.server.ServerZooKeeper.announceBackgroundJobServer(ServerZooKeeper.java:66)
> at org.jobrunr.server.ServerZooKeeper.run(ServerZooKeeper.java:41)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No servers available?!
> ... 12 common frames omitted

i did my configs at application.dev but its still giving same error

> org:
> jobrunr:
> background-job-server:
> enabled: true
> dashboard:
> enabled: true

Answer (score 1):

If your DataSource has `autoCommit` set to `false`, this issue has been fixed in https://github.com/jobrunr/jobrunr/pull/129 .

Please wait for next release (v2.0.2?), or set your `dataSource.autoCommit` to `true` as of now.

Comment: Solved with the release of JobRunr v3.0.0.

Comment: yeah new version solved it for me too (3.0.0)

Comment: I get same error when `jobScheduler.enqueue` is called. Somewhere in the code `opcode` is 0 and that returns null from some map. I am on version 5.1.7 and using inmemory database